# Magento 2: Can we call one observer in another observer?

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, custom, magento-2.1.4

I already have 1 observer on `checkout_cart_product_add_after` .

Before end of `$this` I woule like to call another observer which is located in different module

`magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Observer\AnotherObserver.php`

Both are executing on same event. But both files do different functionality that's why want to make it in separate files.

Don't want to merge code of 2 files in 1 file

Comment: If they are both observing checkout_cart_product_add_after then you wouldn't need to call 1 observer from the other as Magento will execute both. Without actually seeing the code this might not be easily answerable.

Comment: How to set priority which observer should call first?

Comment: @AnkitShah should use `<sequence>` node in `module.xml`

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh it's not working vice versa. I tried in both modules

Comment: Did you clear Magento Cache and try again?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh i just indexed. Seems working fine :) Can post answer & will proceed with necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, should use `<sequence>` in the `module.xml`.

Read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161223/magento-2-same-event-with-multiple-observer-in-different-module-causes-redirect Issue @Khoa