# Magento 2: Same Event with Multiple Observer in Different Module causes redirection issue

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect, magento-2.1.4

Magento 2: Same Event with Multiple Observer in Different Module causes redirection issue

To solve: [Magento 2: Can we call one observer in another observer?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161147/magento-2-can-we-call-one-observer-in-another-observer)

I have followed below code

**magento\app\code\Custom\Second\etc\module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Second" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Custom_First" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\First\etc\frontend\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="first" instance="Custom\First\Observer\FirstObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Second\etc\frontend\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="second" instance="Custom\Second\Observer\SecondObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

My second observer is & causing issue :- [Magento 2: Observer not redirecting to checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161209/magento-2-observer-not-redirecting-to-checkout-page)

Comment: can you find how can we use same events but different observer ?